# Ruby on Rails how 2 create ban with the timer for user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, whenever

I use devise,rails_admin, and started to use gem whenever

Moderator or admin must banned user on 7,14,30 day...

I dont know how to create ban timer for 'banned user' and how to realise it with whenever gem...

Comment: Hi Alexander, wouldn't you just have a cron job that checked for dates that exceed the specified threshold and un-ban the user once the threshold has passed?

Comment: i dont understand how i can do it. 
i created  class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
and it is  created protected method, 

protected

  def banned
    if user.banned_until > Time.now
      user.role == 'banned'
    elsif user.banned_until < Time.now
      user.role == 'user'
    end
  end

but this is still not work, and   this is error i have : 
undefined local variable or method `user' for #<Users::SessionsController